# Reverse for 'blog/article' not found. 'blog/article' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, html, django

I am currently doing a navbar in my django website. However, I'm experiencing some problems with the urls:

I have created another urls.py in a new app called blogs. Here's the code for that:

In the main urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from translator.views import HomeView, TranslatorView

urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('translator/<str:phrase>/', TranslatorView.as_view(), name='translator'),
    path('translated/', TranslatorView.as_view(template_name='main/translated.html'), name='translated'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

In the blog urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ArticleDetailView

app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
 path('', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article' )
]
```

What I want to do is to include the path ArticleDetailView (name='article) in the navbar. So I coded this:

```
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style='background-color: snow;'>
    <div class = 'container'>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="{% static 'C:\Users\marcv\OneDrive\Escriptori\Translate\Scripts\src\static\images\dna_PNG48.png'%}" width="70" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">

      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href='{% url "translator" "phrase" %}'>Translator</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'blog/article' %}" >Blog</a> #Here's the problem
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

However, when I click on the navbar button called Blog (it's in the template), this error raises:

Reverse for 'blog/article' not found. 'blog/article' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I know the error is the name I've given the url in the navbar. However, I don't know which name should I input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The separator between the name space (`app_name='blog'`) and the name of the view `article` is a colon (`:`), not a slash, so:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'blog:article' %}" >Blog</a>
```

Comment: Ok, I certainly had no idea about that. Anyways thanks